# Ember.js: accessing queryParams in before/afterModel hooks

Tags: ember.js

The Ember.js docs indicate that queryParams should be passed into the before/afterModel hooks on a Route (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_afterModel), but that argument is always undefined for me and I haven't been able to figure out why.

Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/xeyaxova/1/edit

Why is this argument undefined, and how else can I access the queryParams inside these hooks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query params must come after the hash, that's where your ember app does all of its routing.

`#/?query=cxZxc`

Example: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/3008#/?query=o

the beforeModel/afterModel hook aren't properly working right now (canary builds)  Here's a workaround, the queryParam object is attached to the transition object.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/giweqeze/1/edit

Comment: Yep, the query params themselves are working fine. My issue is with accessing their values inside of the beforeModel and afterModel hooks on my route.

Comment: That you did, there's a bug in the router, it won't work right now, I'll update with the PR>

Comment: There is a work around for now, the queryParam object is attached to the transition object. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/giweqeze/1/edit

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Is there an issue or PR I can follow?

Comment: I had to run to work for a weekend release, I'll update once I get a PR posted.